# Ubuntu 12.04 - help for sound under Unity, silence under XFCE4

Tags: 12.04, sound, xfce

I have an ubuntu 12.04 install - if I login with a default (Unity) Desktop session sound has always worked out of the box.

I installed XFCE4 and I;m really happy with it but for the fact that there's no sound. I bring up the mixer and set all of the output volumes to max but still hear nothing. The volume keys work in that they show the volume indicator going up and down but still no sound.

I don't know enough about sound under linux to know what's missing or how to debug.

Help needed and appreciated.
---Raymond

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the issue of some switches not being activated. In `xfce4-mixer`, `Select controls...` try to select most items (but look specifically for `Headphone` or `Front`), then in the `Switches` tab make sure that all items listed there are enabled.

[image]

When this doesn't work, I usually resort to `alsamixer` from the command-line.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately my mixer looks nothing like yours and has no "switches" tab.  Reading about this more on the web, it sounds like the xfce4 mixer is not actively supported so I'm looking at alternatives.

Comment: Did you try to enable _all_ controls in `Select controls...`?

Comment: Yes - there were some controls but none elicited a switches tab nor did "Front" or "Headphones" show up anywhere.

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: Thanks. GMTA - I have found and tried alsamixer but also could not get any sound using that.